# .hasClass() on dynamically added class doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm currently writing a simple script using jQuery which check if all the files (sent via AJAX) are properly uploaded before submitting the complete form. So the deal is: when the user drop an image into the browser (drag'n'drop), it's sent to the server using AJAX and when the upload is finished, it simply add a class "**done**" to some div tag.

So whenever the user drops an image, it adds this kind of div:

```
<div class="preview">/* blablabla other div and span classes */</div>
```

And when the upload is complete, it simply looks like this:

```
<div class="preview done">/* blablabla other div and span classes */</div>
```

Everything works like a charm, so here's the interesting part from the form:

```
<form action="target.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
onsubmit="return checkUploadFiles();">
```

It calls this JS function in order to prevent submitting if one files is not fully uploaded yet:

```
function checkUploadFiles(){
    $(".preview").each(function(i, val) {
        if(!val.hasClass('done')){
            alert("Something is not fully uploaded yet, please wait");
            return false;
        };
    });
    return true;
};
```

But... The form is sent anyway, even if there's 15 images uploading right now and 15 div tags having the **.preview** class but not the **.done** class.

I'm sure Iv'e done some stupid mistakes or that's just something I don't know about **.each()** or **.hasClass()**, can someone help please?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: Here's the corrected script, considering the two mistakes I've made:

```
function checkUploadFiles(){
    var ret = true;
    $(".preview").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if(!$this.hasClass('done')){
            alert("Something is not fully uploaded yet, please wait");
            ret = false;
        };
    });
    return ret;
};
```

Comment: try jquerifying the element  like $(val).hasClass

Comment: Aren't you getting an error in the Javascript console? Didn't that help you figure out the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment to provide an alternative to Ethan's method you can just 'jQuerify' the dom element that you are getting in the each loop, so your code would look like this:

```
function checkUploadFiles(){
    var isDone = true;
    $(".preview").each(function(i, val) {
        if(!$(val).hasClass('done')){
            alert("Something is not fully uploaded yet, please wait");
            isDone = false;
        };
    });
    return isDone;
};
```

This method is helpful if you still need the index value as well and avoids any what is `this` confusion.

Edited to also resolve the problem of returning false in the each loop using a boolean variable instead of hard coded boolean values.

Comment: Your `return false` statement is just returning from the `.each()` iteration function, not from `checkUploadFiles`. So `checkUploadfiles` will always return `true`.

Comment: When I posted this answer I was sure that the val being a dom object was a problem I was unsure of the result of calling return false like that, Im working on updating that now.

Comment: @Barmar I've resolved the problem, would you care to update your comment on Ethan's answer as it is misleading now.

Answer (score 3):

You are returning `false` from the each loop, not from the validate method so irrespective of the validation it will always return true.

Also `val` is a dom element reference, not a jQuery object so it doesn't have the `hasClass()` method.

```
function checkUploadFiles() {
    if (!$(".preview").not('.done').length) {
        alert("Something is not fully uploaded yet, please wait");
        return false;
    };
    return true;
};
```

Comment: It was indeed due to val being a dom element, thanks!

Comment: I also corrected the "false" returned from the each loop on my original post.

Answer (score 1):

In .each, `val` (and `this`) are the DOM object, not the jQuery-wrapped object.  So what you want is this instead:

```
function checkUploadFiles(){
    $(".preview").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if(!$this.hasClass('done')){
            alert("Something is not fully uploaded yet, please wait");
            return false;
        };
    });
    return true;
};
```

It's a good idea to create a `$this` variable in case you do anything in callbacks (because you can't trust the value of `this` inside inner functions).

Comment: This has the same problem as Phaeze's answer.